# Is this ExpectiMinimax Tree correctly drawn?

Tags: search, minimax, expectiminimax, homework

I need help with ExpectiMinimax problem:

1. Start a game.
2. The first player flips a coin.
3. The second player flips a coin.
4. The first player decides if he wants to flip another coin.
5. The second player decides if he wants to flip another coin.
6. Game over.

The winner is the player who has earned more points.
The points are computed as follows:

1. If the player flips ones and got the head - 1 point.
2. If the player flips ones and got the tail - 2 points.
3. If the player flips twice and got 2 heads - 4 points.
4. If the player flips twice and got 2 tails - 4 points.
5. If the player flips twice and got one head and one tail - 0 points.

I need to draw the ExpectiMinimax tree associated with this problem, and write the value of each node.

Did I draw the tree properly?

[image: ExpectiMinimax tree]

Answer (score 0):

No, your tree is not an accurate representation of the problem.

Hint: Consider the case where both players flip an H on their first coin. Player 1 decides not to flip a second coin. Is the game over?